# What is the flow of the zooming and scrolling event fired in Telerik Radchart Control?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, telerik, charts, radchart

I am using zooming and scrolling in a Radchart, the Step size is recalculated in the event fired on Scrolling or Zooming.

The problem is: I don't know when does and how many times this event gets fired ? In my application it is called many times when I drag the Scroll Bar or Change the Zoom level.

I am unable to find any documentation of this.

```
RadChart1.DefaultView.ChartArea.ZoomScrollSettingsX.PropertyChanged += ZoomScrollSettingsX_PropertyChanged;
```

The method `ZoomScrollSettingsX_PropertyChanged` is called several times on changing of the zoom level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PropertyChanged event is fired for every property which is changed for the given object i.e. when you scroll it will be thrown for more than one property like RangeStart and RangeEnd for example. You can check the value of e.PropertyName where e is taken from the handler and execute your code for RangeStart and RangeEnd properties only.

Comment: I have checked it, it is always the same property name 'CalculatedMinZoomRange' which gets changed. How can I force this event handler to fire only once even if more than one property changes ?